# Error al instalar "pip" en Lubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

hace un tiempo vengo intentando instalar "pip" para asi poder instalar diferentes librerias, etc.

El problema es que no me lo permite y me tirá como si la dirección estuviese caida

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Devuelve:

```
Fallo al obtener http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.10/libpython3.10-dev_3.10.6-1%7e22.04_amd64.deb 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80
```

Al entrar a la dirección desde el navegador, efectivamente la pagina está caida. ¿Hay alguna otra forma de instalarlo?

Comment: *404 Not Found* El sitio está activo, pero el recurso que pides no existe. También da error si lo haces por el browser. Ni idea.

Comment: Podrías probar este script
`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py` 
`python3 get-pip.py` o el otro método `python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade` que describen en esta página https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: @friveroll 
El primer metodo me aparece como si intentase descargarlo pero apenas se para, me dice Dload 5112k y ahi frena.

El segundo metodo me instala pip pero no me deja usarlo, dice que no está pip instalado. Igualmente parece que encontré el problema. Las cosas no se instalan en el $PATH por lo cual la terminal no sabe donde está para ejecutarlo. El problema, no puedo pasar las cosas a PATH porque dice que no existe... Laputm

Comment: Si puedes ubicar donde quedó instalado pip podrías utilizar un `alias`en `.bashrc` como lo mencionan aquí https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187701/how-do-i-correct-the-path-for-pip

Otra opción sería instalar pyenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), para no depender de la versión de python instalada por defecto en el sistema. Acá hay un tutorial en inglés sobre pyenv https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/

Comment: Por falta de tiempo intenté instalando una nueva maquina virtual, no sé que problema habrá tenido la otra pero en la nueva me dejó instalar "pip" sin problema alguno. Igualmente agradezco la ayuda, preferí hacer una nueva mas que nada por falta de tiempo y porque tampoco tengo cosas importantes en la otra, simplemente paso algunas y listo.

Answer (score 0):

`apt` guarda una versión local de la lista de archivos en el repositorio. Si quien mantiene el paquete actualiza una versión (por ejemplo: el paquete `python3-pip0.1.1` pasa a `python-pip0.1.2`), cuando ejecutes `apt install python3-pip` el instalador buscará el archivo `python3-pip0.1.1`, que ya no existe, y devolverá ese error. Cuando suceda esto, intenta actualizar el repositorio, con

`sudo apt update`

y luego reintentar la instalación.